# SHGetStockIconInfo not found in import table

Tags: delphi, winapi, hook, delphi-xe2

I am developing a resource leak detection tool to monitor the lifecycle of handles in my application. And with handles I mean window handles, brush handles, icon handles, event handles, etc.

I do this by hooking api functions. For example, to monitor a file handle, I hook the CreateFileW and CloseHandle functions by looking for their addresses in the import table and replace them with the addresses of my own functions. My own CreateFileW function calls the original function and stores the handle in a list. My own CloseHandle function calls the original function and removes the handle from the list.

This way I can detect leaks, or handles that are destroyed twice.

I also want to hook the SHGetStockIconInfo function because it can return a handle to an icon, that must be destroyed by the DestroyIcon function. The problem is, that for some reason the SHGetStockIconInfo function does not show up in the import table. Note that I search in the in memory import table. This function is exported by shell32.dll. The only two sheel32 functions that I can find are SHGetFileInfoW and Shell_NotifyIconW.

Note that this function is actually used in the executable. Calling the function works just fine. The function is imported by the WinAPI.ShellAPI Delphi-unit (as external).

Now comes my question. How is it possible that the SHGetStockIconInfo is not present in the in memory import table of my executable? Should not all imported functions be listed in this table?

By the way, I am using Delphi XE2, but C or C++ examples are no problem!

My target platform is Windows 7.

Comment: You don't say what version of Windows you are on. This only exists in Vista and above. On XP this function is missing. See the bottom of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762205(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @patthoyts: Thank you, I just added it to my question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of possible causes for this.

**1. You are not calling the function**

Delphi will only include functions that you actually refer to in the import table. So add a call to the function to your code. You can arrange that the code is never executed, but you'll need to ensure that the smart linker doesn't optimise it away.

Probably the easiest way to do that is to take the address of the function. So you could add this code to the `initialization` section of one of your units:

```
procedure Noop(const Value);
begin
end;

initialization
  Noop(@SHGetStockIconInfo);
```

**2. The function is delay loaded, or explicitly loaded**

In the section above, I'm assuming that you are using a declaration of `SHGetStockIconInfo` that uses the `external` keyword. If you are linking it using a call to `GetProcAddress`, then that will clearly not put it in your import table.

Looking at the declaration of `SHGetStockIconInfo` in the XE2 `ShellAPI` unit I can see that it is delay loaded. That means that it will not appear in your import table, even if you call it. To force the function into your import table you'd need to redeclare it without using delay loading:

```
function SHGetStockIconInfo(siid: SHSTOCKICONID; uFlags: UINT; 
  var psii: TSHStockIconInfo): HResult; stdcall; external shell32;
```

And you'd have to make sure that you included a call to this alternative declaration, for reasons described above.

Of course, doing this would mean that your program would not start on XP because the function doesn't exist. Remember that if you insist on forcing this function into your import table, then it can only ever run on Windows versions that implement the function.

---

If I were you I would contemplate hooking the function in a different way, using a hooking method that does not rely on the function being imported via the import table.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I do actually have a call to this function in my executable. I have edited my question.

Comment: And I've edited the answer. Clearly cause 2 is what is occurring.

Comment: Thank you again! I did not realize that the delay loading feature was the problem here. I also tried using the alternative declatarion method you mentioned, and that does work.

Comment: Maybe this is not the right place to ask, but what other method would you suggest to hook the functions?

Comment: If you are prepared to pay for a good library, I suggest madCodeHook.

Comment: `SHGetStockIconInfo()` is, in fact, delay loaded by the Winapi.ShellApi unit: `function SHGetStockIconInfo; external shell32 name 'SHGetStockIconInfo' delayed;`

Comment: If you don't want to pay for a hooking library, you can still hook delay-loaded functions manually by assigning a [`DliNotifyHook2`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/SysInit.DliNotifyHook2) callback via [`SetDliNotifyHook2()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/SysInit.SetDliNotifyHook2). In the `dliNotePreGetProcAddress` event, you can return a pointer to your own function (you will have to call `GetProcAddress()` directly to get the original function pointer).

Comment: This only works for functions declared as `delayed` though. It is possible for components/libraries, or your own code, to call `GetProcAddress()` directly instead of using delay loading, so you might want to consider hooking `GetProcAddress()` itself so you can check for desired functions being loaded at runtime regardless of the mechanism used to call it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau "SHGetStockIconInfo() is, in fact, delay loaded by the Winapi.ShellApi unit" That's what the answer says.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: your answer mentions it as one of 3 possible reasons (not called, delay loaded, or explicitly loaded) for the OP's original problem, so I am guessing you did not actually check the VCL source to see what it does. I did, and I'm confirming that the function is delay loaded and that is the actual reason for the OP's original problem. That's all.

Comment: @RemyLebeau From the answer: "Looking at the declaration of SHGetStockIconInfo in the XE2 ShellAPI unit I can see that it is delay loaded." Pretty clear.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I didn't see that part earlier.